# asynchronous notification management

Tags: ipc

I have written two daemons which perform IPC via use of SIGIO. However, control is transferred to the signal_handler sometimes whilst important actions are being completed, actions which could be considered as atomic. Is there a way for me to specify that *until the current iteration of a loop is completed we will not transfer control to the signal_handler function*?

thanks in advance
D

note: I am using Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is any better way to do this, but I did the following:

I set a global variable sigio_rec to true in a function sigio_handler, sigio_handler is the function I registered with sigaction() to be invoked when a SIGIO is raised.
At the end of each loop the program checks if sigio_rec is true, if so, then it retrieves data off the socket and continues.

--ttfn

Comment: I managed to find a better way to do this, I noticed that with the use of asynchronous notification when a SIGIO is rasied, my mechanism above results in signal race conditions arising. What I actually needed to do was block the SIGIO, this can be performed with sigprocmask - the code now runs safely.